# SAS Array with or without expander

Tags: performance, raid, zfs, sas

Is it better to use a SAS Expander backplane for 12 drives via one SAS connection or is it better to use a SAS backplane with 3 SAS connections? This is in terms of performance, rather than expansion. This array will be setup using ZFS on a OpenSolaris via a LSI SAS controller as an iSCSI target.

The two products being considered are the SuperMicro [SuperChassis 826A-R1200LPB](http://www.supermicro.com/products/chassis/2U/826/SC826A-R1200LP.cfm) or the [SuperChassis 826E2-R800LPB](http://www.supermicro.com/products/chassis/2U/826/SC826E2-R800LP.cfm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually one of the Mini-SAS ports on an expander is for Failover/JBOD.  Your best performance is to split the disks across a couple controllers (even though they say they support 128+ devices).

You could also set up MPIO if you use two of the same controller (that support MPIO).

Comment: Gotcha.. That makes a lot of sense. Do you have a recommendation of a SAS controller that supports MPIO? Thanks